# virtualenv not activated from crontab on Linux Centos

Tags: python, linux, cron

I'm facing a weird issue.

I need to write a crontab which will invoke a python script, but I need to activate a virtualenv first. This is the crontab I wrote:

```
SHELL = /bin/bash
MAILTO="mail@mail.com"
*/15 * * * * source /srv/python/virtualenvs/proj/bin/activate && /srv/python/virtualenvs/proj/bin/python3.6 /srv/python/proj/Scripts/scheduling.py
```

The script `scheduling.py` try to import data from an oracle DB using `Cx_Oracle`. Crontab gives me an error:

```
[2018-12-05 14:45:02] ERROR - DB connection error: DPI-1047: 64-bit Oracle Client library cannot be loaded: "libclntsh.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory". See https://oracle.github.io/odpi/doc/installation.html
```

So I obviously thought about an error related to Oracle and library `cx_Oracle`.
The weird thing is that if I enter in the linux shell and do

```
source /srv/python/virtualenvs/proj/bin/activate
```

Then type `python` to open a python shell then:

```
import cx_Oracle
import pandas
con = cx_Oracle.connect('parameter_connection')
query = 'select * from tab1 fetch first 5 rows only'
pd.read_sql(query, con = con)
```

it works and gives me query result. I suspect that in `crontab` the virtualenv is not activated properly.

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**in crontab**

```
*/15 * * * * /home/user/script.sh > /dev/null 2>&1
```

**in script.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
source /srv/python/virtualenvs/proj/bin/activate
/srv/python/virtualenvs/proj/bin/python3.6 /srv/python/proj/Scripts/scheduling.py
```

Comment: Yes but I figured out the problem was that crontab has  a minimal environment instnant client oracle path should be added in the script.sh

Comment: I don't know why I got one downvote. I recognize that the question could be misleading ( it's about crontab or about Cx_oracle or virtualenv?) but to me it was not obvious at all that you need to specify path in the script called by crontab.

Comment: No problem it was not directed to you.. I got the feeling that sometimes people use downvote without caution